# Удаление данных из временных таблиц clickhouse

Tags: golang, clickhouse

Есть временная таблица

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (
            ID   Int32
        )
```

Туда в рамках сессии пользователи могут записывать до 1 миллиона записей, чтобы, в последствии, использовать их как подзапрос.
После выборки эти данные не нужны.

Удалить их с помощью не вышло

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DELETE WHERE ID = 1
```

Как можно вычистить данные из временной таблицы?

И что более корректно, если ответ на первый вопрос - никак:

1. Каждый раз создавать таблицу с уникальным именем(основываясь на уникальных параметрах)
2. Использовать обычную таблицу с движком memory и вычищать из неё данные по итогу выборки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы полностью очистить таблицу используйте [TRUNCATE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/truncate/):

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

Удаление части данных из [Memory-engine](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/memory/) таблицы (и построенной на его базе *TEMPORARY TABLE*) не поддерживается:

```
Code: 48. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Mutations are not supported by storage Memory.
```